# Sorting Names in Linked List

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

(This is a Homework Question)I am having trouble implementing a name sort for a linked list. I have the weight(int) sort working now i just want to sort names in ascending order.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int c = 0;
struct node
{
    char name[20];
    int weight;

    node *next;
    node *prev;


};
node*head = NULL;
node *tail = NULL;
node *start_ptr = NULL;
```

Here I create the node and insert into the list in sorted position. I want to do the same for names. A name is assigned a weight(For example a persons weight). It has to be in sorted position so when the print function is called it prints the list in sorted order.

```
void create(int x,char name)
{

    node*p = NULL;
    node*r = NULL;
    node*np = NULL;
        np = new node;
    np->weight = x;
    np->next = NULL;
    np->prev = NULL;
    if (c == 0)
    {
        tail = np;
        head = np;
        p = head;
        p->next = NULL;
        p->prev = NULL;
        c++;
    }
    else
    {
        p = head;
        r = p;
        if (np->weight < p->weight)
        {
            np->next = p;
            p->prev = np;
            np->prev = NULL;
            head = np;
            p = head;
            do
            {
                p = p->next;
            } while (p->next != NULL);
            tail = p;
        }
        else if (np->weight > p->weight)
        {
            while (p != NULL && np->weight > p->weight)
            {
                r = p;
                p = p->next;
                if (p == NULL)
                {
                    r->next = np;
                    np->prev = r;
                    np->next = NULL;
                    tail = np;
                    break;
                }
                else if (np->weight < p->weight)
                {
                    r->next = np;
                    np->prev = r;
                    np->next = p;
                    p->prev = np;
                    if (p->next != NULL)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            p = p->next;
                        } while (p->next != NULL);
                    }
                    tail = p;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void traverse_head()
{
    node *t = head;
    while (t != NULL)
    {
        cout << t->weight << "\t";
        t = t->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


void print_node()
{
    node *temp;
    temp = start_ptr;
    if (temp == NULL) cout << "Empty List!" << endl;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp == NULL) cout << "Empty List!" << endl;



        cout << "Names & weights sorted(ascending) by name. :\n";


        cout << "Name   : " << temp->name << endl;
        cout << "Weight : " << temp->weight << endl;


        cout << "Names & weights sorted(ascending) by weight. : \n";

        cout << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0, n, x;
    char names[20];
    cout << "Enter the number of people: \n";
    cin >> n;
```

A loop that reads in the weight and the name of that person

```
while (i < n)
        {
            cout << "\nEnter Weights: \n";
            cin >> x;
            cout<<"Enter a Name"<<endl;
            cin>>names;
            create(x,*names);
            i++;
        }

        cout << "Output: \n";

        traverse_head();


        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since you said it must be a linked list. So what's the problem with using `strcmp` to sort? Your idea of having two next pointers, one for the list sorted by weight and one for the list sorted by name, seems okay. Just note that that isn't what is usually meant by a "doubly linked list".

Comment: @Sam i updated the code. Basically, i know i'm not executing strcmp properly. I was trying to see if there was another way to sort by name. At the end of void insert i call another function to sort by name. Then that is where i get stuck.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem with sorting (or with something else?).

Comment: @KonstantinL it is with sorting. I am trying to sort alphabetically, but i am having trouble with the code. I will update the code with what i wrote right now.

Comment: If this is a homework please mention it in the question.

Comment: @KonstantinL okay i updated it. as you can see the insertname function is trying to sort the names alphabetically using `strcmp`I just don't believe I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Are your strings plain ansi or with national chars? Or this have no connection with the problem?

Comment: @KonstantinL i believe that has no connection to the problem. Sorry if i am being unclear about the issue.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason whatsoever to use `strcmp` in this program. Why do you think you need it? It is a C-style function for C-style strings. You are not using any in your program. `std::string` objects can be comparet with the normal `<` operator.

Comment: You have "head" points to first element by weight order. But you have no another "head" points to first element by name order. Is it ok?

Comment: okay here it goes. just try this one; while the new input compared to traverse(head in the beginning) is less than zero (strcmp results less than 0 for alphabetically small) move the traverse one level ahead. this while will only break when you are in the correct place to insert the new input. then you will say the next of new input is the next of traverse and the previous's next will be the new input to place it in the middle! bam everything will be sorted while being added

Comment: @koksalb I will give that a try. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: I am on mobile so unfortunately I couldn't write any code. good luck and feel free to ask if you have any problems

Comment: As commented by Konstantinl, you should have a headbyweight, headbyname, tailbyweight, tailbyname. Using a pointer to pointer can simplify the code to avoid having special code for a new node that will be inserted before the first node in the weight or name list, but I don't know if your class has taught pointer to pointer usage.

Comment: @koksalb I redid my code. The problem that i am currently having is reading in the name. All i get is weird jibberish in the console when i call the print function. Am i reading in the name correctly?

Comment: debug it :) when you make cin>>names; then create(x,*names); do you have good names variable going to create function? If not i suspect it is because you put a char[15] for it any not a char array. using char array or string is better if your data is not 100% 15 character long. orelse when you try to print it it will be unassigned and give weird outputs.